# PySpark Identify Duplicates based on Partial Matches from a Column

Tags: pyspark, duplicates, rank

I am looking for a solution to identify an approach to rank the duplicates based on partial match from a Pyspark Dataframe column and tag the first match id to newly generated column.

**Input Dataframe:**

| id | name | class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Roger Fernandes | 12 |
| 2 | Kevin Kingsely | 11 |
| 3 | Fernandes Roger | 13 |
| 4 | Jack Sparrow | 14 |
| 5 | Roger thinker | 16 |
| 6 | Ro seman | 17 |

**Output Dataframe:**

| id | name | class | duplicate | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Roger Ferna | 12 | yes | 1 |
| 2 | Kevin Kingsely | 11 | no | None |
| 3 | Ferna Roger | 13 | yes | 1 |
| 4 | Jack Sparrow | 14 | no | None |
| 5 | Roger think | 16 | yes | 1 |
| 6 | Ro seman | 17 | no | None |

**Note:** We can consider the weightage of partial match as >50%.

**Tried:**

```
partition_dataframe = Window.partitionBy(["name"]).orderBy(order_by_column)
data_frame = data_frame.withColumn("Duplicated_Rank", rank().over(partition_dataframe))
```

**Output Dataframe:**

| id | name | class | duplicate | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Roger Ferna | 12 | yes | 1 |
| 2 | Kevin Kingsely | 11 | no | None |
| 3 | Ferna Roger | 13 | yes | 1 |
| 4 | Jack Sparrow | 14 | no | None |
| 5 | Roger think | 16 | yes | 1 |
| 6 | Ro seman | 17 | no | None |

Comment: Can you add what exactly you mean by partial match? Do want to compare only certain columns?

Comment: Thanks for the initiative to solve this problem @RonakJain. I mean partial match in the way, I have to find the duplicates only based on column "name" however it also consider subset matches in it.

Comment: For example, Name "Roger Ferna" has to be identified as duplicate with both "Roger think" and "Ferna Roger". If you see the match rate here is 50%+. However, it shouldn't match "Ro Seman" because there the match rate is "20%". Only Ro matches in it. Hope I answered your question.